# How can I store a Powershell variable's value as a string while creating ISE submenus

Tags: environment-variables, powershell-ise

I can't seem to articulate my issue well enough within the search engines to find the answer I'm looking for, so I turn to the community for help:

I want to populate my Powershell ISE's menu with submenu items that are in turn populated by a list of modules in a directory so I can load the module with a couple of mouse clicks.

```
$parentProfile = $psISE.CurrentPowerShellTab.AddOnsMenu.SubMenus.Add("Modules",$null,$null)
$mymodules = gci $env:USERPROFILE\documents\windowspowershell\modules |
?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | select name -ExpandProperty name

$i = 0 
foreach ($folder in $mymodules) {
$parentProfile.SubMenus.Add(
 "$folder", {
Import-Module -Name $folder
},
$null # keyboard shortcut
)
}
```

The code works as expected by creating a list of 20 new submenu items under the parent menu item "Modules" but when I click on any of those submenu items:

```
Import-Module : The specified module '_Connect-Office365Service' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
At line:2 char:2
+  Import-Module -Name $folder
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (_Connect-Office365Service:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

The "_Connect-Office365Service" value is the last value or folder processed by the foreach statement. I want the unique and corresponding value of $folder for each folder name found to be part of the submenu item created.

Is this possible? Perhaps there's a better, more elegant approach I can be pointed to? I know there's better ways to get a list of modules I have access to than to search for names in a folder, but regardless of a the source I think I end up with the same problem of passing the wrong (last value) from the variable.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Read and follow *Solving the problem with variable expansion in a script block* in [Variable Substitution in a PowerShell Script Block](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/05/22/variable-substitution-in-a-powershell-script-block/):

> The solution to expanding a variable inside a script block is to do
>   two things:
>
> - create the script block as an expanding string.
> - use the static `Create` method from the `[scriptblock]` class; this will create a script block.

Above citation is slightly truncated. You could modify your script as follows (note appropriate `###` comments):

```
$parentProfile = $psISE.CurrentPowerShellTab.AddOnsMenu.SubMenus.Add("Modules",$null,$null)
$mymodules = Get-ChildItem $env:USERPROFILE\documents\windowspowershell\modules |
    Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer } | 
        Select-Object name -ExpandProperty name
$i = 0 
foreach ($folder in $mymodules) {
    $auxStringBlock = "Import-Module -Name $folder" ### create the script block as an expanding string.
    $parentProfile.SubMenus.Add(
        "$folder", 
        [scriptblock]::Create( $auxStringBlock), ### use the static `Create` method from the `[scriptblock]` class
        $null  # keyboard shortcut
    )
}
```